# Через samba не расшаривается примонтированный локальный диск

Tags: ubuntu, share, samba

Есть компьютер, два жестких диска, на одном система (Ubuntu), на втором файлы, оба винта в ext4. В fstab прописано автоматическое монтирование второго жесткого диска при старте системы, все работает идеально, так же имеется настроенная и рабочая самба, которая успешно расшаривает каталоги на первом диске, но вот примонтированный диск она расшарить не может.
Диск монтируется в каталог /media/user/disk2, на каталог установлены чмод 777 и човн ноубади/ноугруп, но это не играет роли, так как после монтирования диска в каталог права все равно сбрасываются и диск не видно как расшареный, точнее каталог видно, но зайтив него нельзя, как быть в таком случае? Как-то монтировать его с нужными правами или в конфиге самбы что-то прописать?

Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Выполните chmod _после_ монтирования. Это изменит права на корень диска. И конечно вместо установки таких не безопасных прав можно самбе явно указать в описании шары под каким пользователем работать, надо указать пользователя, которому точно хватит прав для работы с разделом

Comment: chmod после монтирования я естественно пробовал :) Это ничего не дает, он даже не меняет права. Права 777 на каталог в данный момент нужны для теста, чтобы хотя бы заработало, потом я выставлю нужные.

Comment: Конфиг самбы покажите.

Comment: Конфиг самбы:

[global]
workgroup = WORKGROUP
server string = Samba Server %v
#netbios name = PC
security = user
map to guest = bad user
name resolve order = bcast host
dns proxy = no
bind interfaces only = yes
usershare owner only = false

[Public]
path = /media/emeykey/Storage
writable = yes
guest ok = yes
guest only = no
read only = no
create mode = 0777
directory mode = 0777
force user = nobody

Comment: Монтирование в /etc/fstab/: UUID=9a0078d3-c7e4-4f22-a915-80bf0d512760 /media/emeykey/Storage    ext4    defaults 0       2

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос закрыт. Убрал гостевой доступ, сделал доступ по юзернейму и паролю, и о чудо, оно заработало. Пусть будет так.

Comment: http://smb-conf.ru/absolyutnaya-fajlopomojka.html
а так не пробовал?